# App does not uploaded on iOS App connect store with reason non-public APIs

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I am trying to upload my App on Apple store. But app got rejected with reason non-public APIs.Whole reason for rejection is given below:

> Dear Developer,
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "AppName". > Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public
> symbols in Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: _ptrace. If method
> names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above,
> altering your method names will help prevent this app from being
> flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of
> the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included
> with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information,
> visit the Technical Support Information at
> http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

I tried many times but got same error message. If anyone solve this problem please help.

Comment: can you please share the Github link, i just wanna have a look on plugins and methods name

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because App Store questions are off topic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you are submitting a debug build. [You can find discussion of the same problem here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37850).

Did you copied the build after running `flutter run`?

Or you might have missed `flutter build ios --release`

Comment: use `flutter clean` first